# Cómo configurar mercure hub y enviar notificación a la interfaz de usuario en aplicación web Symfony

Tags: symfony, notificaciones, mercure-hub

Estoy iniciándome en el empleo de Mercure hub pero tengo algunas lagunas que no me permiten avanzar; la idea es agregar a la aplicación (es una aplicacion web tradicional de gestion de información con symfony 5.4 que he venido actualizando desde sf3) la clásica notificación (campanita) a los usuarios ante una determinada acción de alguno de los usuarios, en este caso concreto al registrar una nueva solicitud de traslado de una embarazada, se debe activar la campanita en el dashboard del usuario que pertenece a la unidad de salud donde actualmente está registrada la embarazada para su aprobación. Es una funcionalidad sencilla pero me dará la idea para ir agregando notificaciones en tiempo real más complejas.

Hasta el momento esto es lo que tengo y las dudas que me han surgido:

```
composer require mercure
```

Descargué el ejecutable de mercure para Windows.

2 - Cree las variables de entorno necesarias:

```
//env.local.php:
return array(    
    'MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN' => 'doctrine://default',
    'MERCURE_URL' => 'https://localhost:3000/.well-known/mercure',
    'MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL' => 'https://pami.local:3000/.well-known/mercure',
    'MERCURE_JWT_SECRET' => 'm3rcu353cr37pa55pra53DEV'
);
```

según entiendo MERCURE_URL es la dirección de comunicación del servidor web con mercure hub, y MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL es la dirección para la subscripcion desde el lado del cliente al hub.
La primera duda, en base a qué datos debo generar el MERCURE_JWT_SECRET ??? Este será un token stateless?? almacenado en una variable de entorno y que no debe cambiar??

Teniendo las variables de entorno definidas, esta es la receta *mercure.yaml*:

```
mercure:
    hubs:
        default:
            url: '%env(MERCURE_URL)%'
            public_url: '%env(MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL)%'
            jwt:
                secret: '%env(MERCURE_JWT_SECRET)%'
                publish: '*'
```

**Duda**: No entiendo la composición del `JWT`, en el formato del mercure bundle, qué debe contener la sección publish de esta receta??

Este es el action que debería generar la notificación, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
 /**
         * 
         * @param Request $request
         * @param ManagerRegistry $manager
         * @param UserInterface $user
         * @param UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder
         * @param LoggerInterface $logger
         * @param \Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface $messageBus
         * @return Response
         * @throws Exception
         * @throws type
         */
        public function solicitarTrasladoAction(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $manager, UserInterface $user, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder, LoggerInterface $logger, \Symfony\Component\Messenger\MessageBusInterface $messageBus): Response
        {
            if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
                try {
                    if (!$request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_POST)) {
                        return new Response("Operación no soportada!!!", 500);
                    }
    
                    $id = $uuidEncoder->decode($request->request->get('embarazadaId', null));
                    $cmfDestinoId = $uuidEncoder->decode($request->get('cmfDestino', null));
    
                    $em = $manager->getManager();
                    $nuevaSolicitudTraslado = new \App\Entity\SolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada();
                    $conn = $em->getConnection();
                    $conn->beginTransaction();
                    try {
    
                        $cmfDestino = $manager->getRepository(EstructuraOrganizativa::class)->findOneJoinTipoEstructuraOrganizativa($cmfDestinoId);
                        if (\is_null($cmfDestino)) {
                            throw new \Exception("No se encontró la unidad de destino.", 404);
                        } else if ($cmfDestino->getTipoEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId() !== 6) {
                            throw new \Exception("No es posible ubicar una embarazada fuera de un CMF.", 406);
                        }
    
                        $embarazada = $em->getRepository(Embarazada::class)->findOneJoinEstructuraOrganizativa($id);
                        if (\is_null($embarazada)) {
                            throw new \Exception("No se encontró la embarazada solicitada", 404);
                        }
    
                        if ($embarazada->getEstructuraOrganizativa()->getId() === $cmfDestino->getId()) {
                            throw new \Exception("No es posible reubicar la embarazada en el CMF al que pertenece actualmente.", 406);
                        }
    
                        $posibleSolicitud = $em->getRepository(\App\Entity\SolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada::class)->findOneBy(['embarazada' => $embarazada, 'estado' => 'solicitado']);
                        if (!\is_null($posibleSolicitud)) {
                            throw new \Exception("Ya existe una solicitud de traslado para esta paciente.", 406);
                        }
    
                        
                        $nuevaSolicitudTraslado->setEmbarazada($embarazada);
                        $nuevaSolicitudTraslado->setCmfDestino($cmfDestino);
                        $nuevaSolicitudTraslado->setEstado("solicitado");
                        $nuevaSolicitudTraslado->setAsunto("Solicitud de traslado");
                        $nuevaSolicitudTraslado->setMensaje(\sprintf("Solicito reubicar a '%s' hacia provincia '%s', municipio '%s', CMF: %s.", $embarazada->getNombre(), $cmfDestino->getParent()->getParent()->getParent()->getParent()->getTitle(), $cmfDestino->getParent()->getParent()->getParent()->getTitle(), $cmfDestino->getTitle()));
    
                        $em->persist($nuevaSolicitudTraslado);
                        $em->flush();
                        $conn->commit();
                    } catch (\Exception $exc) {
                        $conn->rollback();
                        $conn->close();
    
                        if (in_array($exc->getCode(), array(404, 406))) {
                            return new Response($exc->getMessage(), 500);
                        }
    
                        $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", __CLASS__, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));
                        return new Response("Ocurrió un error inesperado al ejecutar la operación", 500);
                    }
    
                    $messageBus->dispatch(new \App\Message\NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessage($uuidEncoder->encode($nuevaSolicitudTraslado->getIdPublico())));
    
                    return new Response("La solicitud de traslado fue enviada satisfactoriamente");
                } catch (\Exception $exc) {
                    $logger->error(sprintf("[%s:%s]: %s", self::class, __FUNCTION__, $exc->getMessage()));
                    return new Response("Ocurrió un error inesperado al ejecutar la operación", 500);
                }
            } else {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException("Recurso no encontrado");
            }
        }
```

Antes de enviar la respuesta al usuario de que se generó correctamente la solicitud y para lograr un comportamiento asincrónico agrego un mensaje al componente de mensajería de symfony configurado (en este caso uso Doctrine como transporte), pasando en el contenido de este el idPublico del nuevo registro de solicitud creado:

```
// contenido de la receta messenger.yaml
    framework:
        messenger:
            # Uncomment this (and the failed transport below) to send failed messages to this transport for later handling.
            failure_transport: failed
            reset_on_message: true
            transports:
                # https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#transport-configuration
                async: 
                    dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                    options:
                        auto_setup: false
                failed: 
                    dsn: '%env(MESSENGER_TRANSPORT_DSN)%'
                    options:
                        queue_name: 'failed'
                sync: 'sync://'

            routing:
                # Route your messages to the transports
                 'App\Message\NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessage': async
```

Esta es la clase que representa el mensaje simple:

```
namespace App\Message;

class NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessage
{

    private $content;

    public function __construct(string $content)
    {
        $this->content = $content;
    }

    public function getContent(): string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }
}
```

Y este el handler de dicho mensaje, entiendo aquí es donde continuaría la lógica del mercure hub:

```
use App\Message\NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessage;
use App\Repository\SolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaRepository;
use App\Services\UuidEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\HubInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Mercure\Update;
use Symfony\Component\Messenger\Handler\MessageHandlerInterface;

/**
 * Envia al Mercure bus la nueva solicitud de traslado para ser notificada a los usuarios
 */
class NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessageHandler implements MessageHandlerInterface
{

    private $mercureHub;
    private $repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada;
    private $uuidEncoder;

    public function __construct(HubInterface $mercureHub, SolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaRepository $repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada, UuidEncoder $uuidEncoder)
    {
        $this->mercureHub = $mercureHub;
        $this->repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada = $repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada;
        $this->uuidEncoder = $uuidEncoder;
    }

    public function __invoke(NotificacionSolicitudTrasladoEmbarazadaMessage $message)
    {
        // hacer algo con el mensaje, por ejemplo: enviar una notificacion al hub de mercure
        $idPublico = $this->uuidEncoder->decode($message->getContent());

        $solicitud = $this->repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada->findOneBy(['idPublico' => $idPublico]);
        /** si no existe el registro hacer fallar el mensaje* */
        /** Contar la cantidad de solictudes aun no atendidas para la unidad de destino, se debe mostrar al lado de la campanita en la UI * */
        $totalNoAtendidas = $this->repositorySolicitudTrasladoEmbarazada->contarNoAtendidas($solicitud->getCmfDestino());

        $actualizacion = new Update(
                'https://the-uri-of-resource', // Esta URI debe ser generada con el sistema de enrutamiento interno de symfony??                
                \json_encode(['ultimaSolictud' => $solicitud->getAsunto(), 'totalNoAtendidas' => $totalNoAtendidas]),
                true // privado necesita jwt auth
        );

        $this->mercureHub->publish($actualizacion);

        return new Response("Publicado");
    }
}
```

**Duda**: El parámetro URI que se le pasa la clase `Update` deberá ser una url generada con el routing de symfony?? o es una formalidad??

Hasta este punto los mensajes se quedan almacenados en la cola de mensajes, reintentándose enviar al mercure hub porque el publish() falla por los problemas de configuración que señalé anteriormente y por tanto no se ejecuta correctamente el mercure.exe.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
En el caso del lado del cliente, aun no entiendo muy bien la parte de configurar de establecer el JWT, eso lo dejaré para otra pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya dí con la solución, aun me queda por entender algunos conceptos del componente Messenger de Symfony que ayudan a desacoplar el código, pero para este caso al menos me sirve para iniciar:

El principal problema estaba en la `recipe` de Mercure, quedando de la siguiente manera el fichero `mercure.yaml`:

```
mercure:
    hubs:
        default:
            url: '%env(MERCURE_URL)%'
            public_url: '%env(MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL)%'
            jwt:
                secret: '%env(MERCURE_JWT_SECRET)%'
                publish: ['stnotif']
                subscribe: ['stnotif']
```

Tanto en **publish** como en **subscribe** establezco el nombre del **topic** bajo el cual se va a publicar en el hub de Mercure, y al cual desde la aplicación nos suscribiremos.

Estas dos configuraciones garantizan se genere adecuadamente el JWT en el formato esperado por Mercure.

Otro aspecto, la aplicación es accesible mediante HTTPS, por tanto las variables de entorno `MERCURE_URL` y `MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL` deben apuntar al mismo dominio, en este caso es un virtual host con un dominio ficticio, haciendo posible el intercambio de la cookie de session entre la aplicación web y el hub de mercure. Quedando dichas variables en el fichero `.env.local`: de la siguiente manera:

```
'MERCURE_URL' => 'https://pami.local:3000/.well-known/mercure',
'MERCURE_PUBLIC_URL' => 'https://pami.local:3000/.well-known/mercure',
'MERCURE_JWT_SECRET' => 'MySecret',
```

La otra adecuación la realicé en el Caddy file del binario de Mercure, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
# Learn how to configure the Mercure.rocks Hub on https://mercure.rocks/docs/hub/config
{
    {$GLOBAL_OPTIONS}
}

{$SERVER_NAME:pami.local:3000}

tls C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf\ssl\pami.local.crt C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.41\conf\ssl\pami.local.key

route {
    encode zstd gzip

    mercure {
        # Transport to use (default to Bolt)
        transport_url {$MERCURE_TRANSPORT_URL:bolt://mercure.db}
        # Publisher JWT key
        publisher_jwt {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_PUBLISHER_JWT_ALG}
        # Subscriber JWT key
        subscriber_jwt {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY} {env.MERCURE_SUBSCRIBER_JWT_ALG}
        cors_origins https://pami.local
        publish_origins https://pami.local
        # Extra directives
        {$MERCURE_EXTRA_DIRECTIVES}
    }

    respond /healthz 200

    respond "Not Found" 404
}
```

Importante destacar de este fichero:

1. Se establece como `SERVER_NAME` el nombre de dominio por el cual se llamará al hub de Mercure y el puerto.
2. Se establece como valor de la directiva **tls** las rutas de los ficheros `.crt` y `.key` relacionados al certificado de seguridad de la aplicación.
3. Las directivas **cors_origins** y **publish_origins** apuntan a la dirección URL de la aplicación, evitando que se genere un error `CORS`

Por último, del lado del cliente en la vista `twig`, se crea un objeto de tipo EventSource implementando los eventos asociados, para ello se completa con la url del servidor Mercure (mediante la función twig que implementa el Mercure bundle) y el `URI` del topic al que nos suscribiremos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const eventSource = new EventSource("{{ mercure('stnotif', { subscribe:'stnotif'})|escape('js')}}", {withCredentials: true});

    eventSource.onopen = function () {
        console.log('Socket opened!');
    }

    eventSource.onmessage = function (e) {
        console.log('Notificacion recibida!');
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        document.querySelectorAll('.totalNotifNoAtendidas').forEach(function (el) {
            el.innerHTML = data.totalNoAtendidas;
        });
    }

    eventSource.onerror = function () {
        console.log('Error en el socket!');
    }
</script>
```

Con estos ajustes funciona adecuadamente la "notificación en tiempo real" de la cantidad de solicitudes pendientes que van registrándose.

Answer (score 0):

Respecto a las preguntas que tienes:

> Duda: No entiendo la composición del JWT, en el formato del mercure
> bundle, qué debe contener la sección publish de esta receta??

En este aspecto puedes encontrar la configuracion completa en https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html, pero en este caso estas permitiendo publicar en todos los buckets de mercure.

Respecto a esta duda:

> Duda: El parámetro URI que se le pasa la clase Update deberá ser una
> url generada con el routing de symfony?? o es una formalidad??

Parece ser que si es mandatoria, puedes tomar este curso: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/turbo/mercure-php y puedes generar la url a partir del parametro